# Cpanel NodeJS app displaying source code

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, node.js, cpanel

I have set up nodeJS app on cpanel using cpanel nodeJS selector. Apps root directory is `/home/userName/public_html/server`. The app is working fine.

Problem is if I send get request to `example.com/server/app.js` it is displaying the source code of app.js in the browser.

How do I prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create put your app.js or application root not in folder `public_html`. just create folder in `/home/userName/nodejs` or something like that.